# How to fill missing text values with NA while scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using `beautifulsoup` to create two `dataframes` of unique classes with text.

The first `dataframe` has a few missing values that is messing up the alignment in rows when I join them. I tried to use an if not statement but I still get error: `get_text() is empty`.

```
      soup = bs(response.text, 'html5lib')
      for x in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "details_table"}):
        S = x.find("span", {"class": "search_line_s details_table_data"}).get_text(strip=True)
        if not x.find("span", {"class": "search_line_a__ details_table_data"}).get_text(strip=True):
          A = "N/A"
        else:
          A = x.find("span", {"class": "search_line_a__ details_table_data"}).get_text(strip=True)
        App = x.find("span", {"class": "search_line_app details_table_data"}).get_text(strip=True)
        df3.loc[len(df3.index)] = [S, A, App]
      for items in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "e_link"}):
        item_at = items.attrs
        list_of_dict_values = item_at.values()
        good_objects = [True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False]
        property_asel = [val for is_good, val in zip(good_objects, list_of_dict_values) if is_good]
        link = property_asel[0]
        type = property_asel[1]
        name = property_asel[2]
        category = property_asel[3]
        sub_category = property_asel[4]
        price = property_asel[5]
        df.loc[len(df.index)] = [name, category, sub_category, type, price, link]
        fac.append(items.get_text(strip=True))
        result = pd.concat([df, df3], axis=1)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid calling `.get_text(strip=True)` in your condition, cause you have to check if the element itself is available:

```
if not x.find("span", {"class": "search_line_a__ details_table_data"}):
    ...
```

or

```
 A = x.find("span", {"class": "search_line_a__ details_table_data"}).get_text(strip=True) if x.find("span", {"class": "search_line_a__ details_table_data"}) else "N/A"
```

or with `walrus operator` (needs python 3.8 and higher):

```
 A = e.get_text(strip=True) if (e:=x.find("span", {"class": "search_line_a__ details_table_data"})) else "N/A"
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution was perfect! Happy Thanksgiving!